# Downloading avatars (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js, avatar

I have the usual familiar avatar command.

```js
let target = interaction.options.getMember("target");
let embed = new MessageEmbed();
embed.setColor('RANDOM');
embed.setTitle(`Avatar by ${target.user.tag}`);
embed.setDescription(`Download Avatar\n[[PNG]](${target.user.displayAvatarURL({format: 'png', size: 4096, dynamic: false})})┃[[JPG]](${target.user.displayAvatarURL({format: 'jpg', size: 4096, dynamic: false})})┃[[GIF]](${target.user.displayAvatarURL({format: 'gif', size: 4096, dynamic: true})})`);
embed.setImage(target.user.displayAvatarURL({size: 4096, dynamic: true}));
interaction.followUp({embeds: [embed]});
```

Everything is fine, of course, everything works. Help is worth downloading avatars.
But if I click on the image that is embedded and copy the link, then the "images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/" link is copied, and when I follow this link, the avatar starts downloading immediately without first looking at it in the browser. In the description no such the link, it starts with "cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/", and when I click on this link, I can see the avatar, but downloading avatar does not start immediately, for this I need to click two more times to download from the browser.
How can I make it so that by clicking on the link in the description downloading avatar starts immediately?

Answer (score 0):

**Hey there!**

I'm pretty sure you're asking how to download something with one link of discord.

A simple fix to this is leading to a link that saves discord avatars, I don't know any examples at the top of my head, however, you can link it to the discord avatar link: cdn.discord.com/avatars/${USER_ID}/

Comment: Yes, I can, but there is an incident. For example, my avatar: "https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/cDNyE7m8GN79ymsw9ZpuViG_qQTIjGFCAV6k7hYFE4M/%3Fsize%3D1024/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/546359252575322122/61bae42e4e0d1523f09327e7557b221b.png", where "546359252575322122" my ID and "61bae42e4e0d1523f09327e7557b221b" name of the avatar. But what is "cDNyE7m8GN79ymsw9ZpuViG_qQTIjGFCAV6k7hYFE4M"? Each user has a different character set. One small change in these symbols results in the site being unable to be accessed.